# How to implement two integers multiplication using recursion?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to implement two n integers multiplication using recursion, here is the pseudo code.
[image: Recursion Integer multiplication pseudo code]

Here is what I tried, and didn't get a correct result.

```
const recurIntMultiplication = (x, y) => {
  const length = x.toString().length;
  if (length == 1) return x * y;
  else {
    let [a, b] = getHalfs(x);
    let [c, d] = getHalfs(y);

    let ac = recurIntMultiplication(a, c);
    let ad = recurIntMultiplication(a, d);
    let bc = recurIntMultiplication(b, c);
    let bd = recurIntMultiplication(b, d);

    return 10 ** length * ac + (10 ** length / 2) * (ad + bc) + bd;
  }
};

const getHalfs = num => {
  const length = num.toString().length / 2;
  return [~~(num / 10 ** length), num % 10 ** length];
};

console.log(recurIntMultiplication(5678, 1234));
```

Comment: Does it work for two-digit numbers? If not, where does it go wrong? If it works for two-digit numbers but not four-digit numbers, where does it go wrong?

Comment: It only  works for a single digit, which is obvious.

Comment: ...so where does it go wrong?

Comment: On the return statement, see the answer.

Comment: Also, it seems clear to me that you are supposed to implement addition and power-of-10 multiplication yourself, and that x and y are not javascript numbers but rather strings or arrays of arbitrary length. Also, the notion of "halve" requires some thought when `n` is an odd integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10 ** length / 2` is interpreted as `(10 ** length) / 2` rather than `10 ** (length / 2)`.